# Cascading dropdowns using sharepoint?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

How can I create cascading dropdowns using sharepoint lists with jquery, as well as an add new row button for cascading dropdowns. Additionally, I want to be able to save all the rows of data saved in a sharepoint list using sharepoint designer?

[like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlZab.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create 3 lists for Country,State,City and use lookup column to connect them.

Then create another list to include these three column by lookup to these three list, then use some Jquery to do Cascading DropDowns, here is a detailed example for your reference:

[Cascading DropDownList In SharePoint](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/cascading-dropdownlist-in-sharepoint)